# Installation: Redmine on Ubuntu EC2 instance

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redmine

I need to install redmine in a Amazon VPS. I'm following this post: https://fosskb.in/2015/02/23/installing-redmine-on-ubuntu-14-04/ but I have an error when I try to install by apt.

I followed the instructions of the same post in a VirtualBox machine and I had any problem, It was found very well.

This is the error:

```
dbconfig-common: writing config to /etc/dbconfig-common/redmine/instances/default.conf
Creating config file /etc/dbconfig-common/redmine/instances/default.conf with new version
Creating config file /etc/redmine/default/database.yml.new with new version
granting access to database redmine_default for redmine_default@localhost: already exists.
creating database redmine_default: success.
verifying database redmine_default exists: success.
dbconfig-common: flushing administrative password
Creating config file /etc/redmine/default/database.yml with new version
Creating config file /etc/redmine/default/session.yml with new version
A new secret session key has been generated in /etc/redmine/default/session.yml
Populating database for redmine instance "default".
This may take a while.
rake aborted!
(<unknown>): did not find expected alphabetic or numeric character while scanning an alias at line 7 column 13
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
Error when running rake db:migrate, check database configuration.
dpkg: error processing package redmine (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Where can be the error?

Answer (score 0):

It is a known bug in Redmine installation. Do one thing

```
sudo nano /etc/redmine/default/database.yml
```

Change adapter from msyql to mysql2 and re run

```
sudo apt-get install redmine redmine-mysql
```

Comment: Hey error2007, Thank's for your recommendation, I have setting "mysql2" but I have the same error. Any idea?